# Android Studio - setBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I'm creating a TextView, and I'm seting the size I would like to set the background to a drawable using setBackground or setBackgroundResource, however whenever I do it, it changes the size of the background. It doesn't do it if I create a view in the XML file, though.

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gold_edged);
    mEventView.setBackground(drawable);
    mEventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mEventView.setPadding(24,0,24,0);
    mEventView.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mEventView.setHeight((int)(height*context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    //mEventView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    mEventView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    mEventView.setText(message);
```

This is the code, and when setBackgroundColor isn't commented out it goes back to the original sizes but I do not want that color as the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that `setWidth` is taking the exact width in pixels as argument, so giving it a `MATCH_PARENT` will set the width to 0. If you want to have its width to match parent, then you should apply it on its `LayoutParams` only:

```
layoutParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
mEventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Yes this is true, I had just put this there for testing purposes, however either way this width is not the width being displayed nor is the height right.

Comment: The values in LayoutParams affect your TextView, as described in the doc: "This value is used for width calculation if LayoutParams does not force TextView to have an exact width." So you could try set the params with WRAP_CONTENT, and give exact pixels for `setWidth`.

Comment: This is not the problem though, the problem that is occurring is that these parameters do not mean anything and the width and height is just being overwritten to be the width and height of the background.

Comment: Have you tried `layoutParams.width = 100` or `layoutParams.height = 100` or similar?

Comment: Yes, setting the parameters is not the problem, as if i set the background using setBackgroundColor() all the sizes and parameters are fine, but I want the background to be a drawable not a color.

Comment: Right, sorry I'm a little bit confused. Silly question, are you calling `setBackground` and `setBackgroundColor` together?

Comment: no I just want to call setBackground and have the parameters not change, the setBackgroundColor was just there to show that the background is the thing changing the size.